# Install oracle plugin for geoserver 2.2-SNAPSHOT

Tags: plugins, geoserver

How install oracle plugin for geoserver with version 2.2-snapshot? For what version geoserver extensions. I find only 2.2, 2.2.1 etc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Copy from

```
 http://repo.opengeo.org/org/geotools/
```

for

```
      8-SNAPSHOT
```

and paste

```
    ../webapps/geoserver/WEB-INF/lib/
```

then restart opengeo(tomcat).